# Make a vertical Wordpress navbar submenu horizontal

Tags: css, wordpress, uinavigationbar, navbar, horizontallist

I want to change my Wordpress navbar so that the dropdown that appears when you hover over a page with subpages positions itself horizontally, not vertically. My "main" navbar is already horizontal, I want the "subnavbar" to be, as well.

A picture says a thousand words:

Current (without hovering)...

| Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 | Page 4 |

Current (mouse hovering over Page 2)...

```
| Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 | Page 4 |
         | Subpage 1 |
         | Subpage 2 |
         | Subpage 3 |
         | Subpage 4 |
         | Subpage 5 |
```

What I want (mouse hovering over Page 2)...

```
| Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 | Page 4 |
         | Subpage 1 | Subpage 2 | Subpage 3 |
| Subpage 4 | Subpage 5 |
```

I hope that was clear -- and for the record, I'm using the **Fistic** theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the id or class for the subnav - and use `float:left` to make them line up next to each other instead of below each other.

Comment: What am I looking for? Is it a list? I see a label tag/property...? I also see #menu a:hover properties.

Comment: Yes - in the subnav, they should be list items <li>. Would you mind showing me the site?

Comment: @user1729886 Just looked at a sample of the site. It looks like the children of the menu are under the css class: #menu ul ul li, #menu ul ul ul li. Try setting that to float:left instead of float:none.

Comment: Interesting, but no cigar. The tab with about 14 subpages is at least listing them in pairs horizontally for the first 6 or so pages :-/ The problem seems to be the width of the parent element -- it only "extends" to about halfway across the next tab. Shorter-titled pages fit next to one another, but those with longer titles are forced to their own line. The site is eswenergy.com

Comment: @user1729886 Okay - you need to increase the ul.children width to whatever you want it to be. But it shows it as a blob then - so you might want to consider breaking the menu into columns.